# How to set value for extjs combo after combo load?

Tags: extjs, combobox

How to set value for extjs combo after combo load?

I have a Country combo (I have bind this json store).

How to set default value as United States?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is value property for combobox.

If you know the code for the default value you can try using it.

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
    ...
    value: 'US',
    ...
});
```